# Combining and transposing multiple timeseries with Excel PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table of timeseries data, where each entry is associated with a date interval.  Is there a way to combine and merge different timeseries into a single time series?

Given input Table1:

```
|Role|From      |To        |Value|
|A   |01.01.2017|15.01.2017|    1|
|A   |16.01.2017|01.02.2017|    2|
|A   |02.02.2017|28.02.2017|    2|
|B   |16.01.2017|05.03.2017|    5|
|B   |06.03.2017|31.03.2017|    7|
```

Can I transform this *automatically* using PowerQueryinto the following (note the use of merged intervals):

```
|From|01.01.2017|16.01.2017|02.02.2017|01.03.2017|06.03.2017|
|To  |15.01.2017|01.02.2017|28.02.2017|05.03.2017|31.03.2017|
|A   |         1|         2|         2|          |          |
|B   |          |         5|         5|         5|         7|
|Sum |         1|         7|         7|         5|         7|
```

Comment: You'd need a source of "master" intervals to check against.

Comment: Thanks, how can I generate that source based on the available intervals from the two different sets (A and B) in power query?  In other words, I need to find every case of overlap between the two sets of intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of your code. It is a little shorter and probably more straightforward. Also it returns exactly the same result as in the example.

```
let
    // Data source
    SourceTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Data = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceTable,{{"Role", type text}, {"From", type datetime}, {"To", type datetime}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),

    //Get a list of roles. 
//    Roles = {"A", "B", "C", "D"}, //Example line. Comment it
    Roles = List.Transform(Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(SourceTable, {"Role"}))[Role], each Text.Trim(Text.Upper(_))),
    // Create table of all possible intervals
    UnionTables = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
                        Table.Combine({
                               Table.SelectColumns(SourceTable, "From"), 
                               Table.SelectColumns(Table.AddColumn(Table.SelectColumns(SourceTable, "To"), "From", each Date.AddDays([To], 1)), {"From"}) //Add 1 day to ensure next interval starts at the same date to produce no fake 1-day intervals
                        }), 
                  {{"From", type datetime}}),
    SortDates = Table.Sort(Table.Distinct(UnionTables), {{"From", Order.Ascending}}),
    AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(SortDates, "Index", 0, 1),
    AllIntervals = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(Table.AddColumn(AddIndex, "To", each Date.AddDays(AddIndex[From]{[Index] + 1}, -1), type datetime)), //Substract 1 day to revert intervals to their original values
    AddColumns = Table.Combine(List.Transform(Roles, (Role) => Table.AddColumn(Table.SelectColumns(AllIntervals, {"From", "To"}), Role, (x) => List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(Data, (y) => Text.Upper(Text.Trim(y[Role])) = Role and ((y[From] >= x[From] and y[To] <= x[To]) or (y[From] <= x[From] and y[To] >= x[To])))[Value]), type number))),
    GetDistinctRows = Table.Distinct(AddColumns),
    FilterOutNulls = Table.SelectRows(GetDistinctRows, each List.MatchesAny(Record.FieldValues(Record.SelectFields(_, Roles)), (x) => x <> null) /*List.Match(Table.ColumnNames(AddColumns), Roles) <> null*/),
    AddSum = Table.AddColumn(FilterOutNulls, "Sum", each List.Sum(Record.FieldValues(Record.SelectFields(_, Roles)))),
    ListOfNonNullColumns = 
        List.Select(
            List.Transform(Roles, (x) => if (
                Table.RowCount(
                    Table.SelectRows(AddSum, (y) => 
                          List.Sum(
                                Record.FieldValues(
                                      Record.SelectFields(y, {x})
                                ) 
                          ) > 0
                    )
                )
            ) > 0 then x else null)
        , each _ <> null),

    CleanAndReorder =  Table.SelectColumns(AddSum, List.Combine({{"From", "To"}, ListOfNonNullColumns, {"Sum"}})),
    DemoteHeaders = Table.DemoteHeaders(CleanAndReorder),
    Result = Table.Transpose(DemoteHeaders)
in
    Result
```

Comment: Great, I forgot to specify, but in my case I need the option to have an arbitrary number of roles.

Comment: @f.carlsen I've updated the answer to meet this new requirement. It is more complicated now, mostly due to the need to filter out empty columns. If you don't need this, remove step `ListOfNonNulColumns` and replace `CleanAndReorder` with `CleanAndReorder =  Table.SelectColumns(AddSum, List.Combine({{"From", "To"}, Roles, {"Sum"}})),`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to do it, code in M for power query below with comments on individual steps:

```
let
    // Data source
    SourceTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Data = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceTable,{{"Role", type text}, {"From", type datetime}, {"To", type datetime}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),

    // Create table of all possible intervals
    AllDates =      Table.Sort(
                     Table.Distinct(
                       Table.Combine({
                               Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(SourceTable, "From"), {"From", "Date"}), 
                               Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(SourceTable, "To"), {"To", "Date"})
                       })
                      ), {{"Date", Order.Ascending}}
                     ), 
    RenameFrom = Table.RenameColumns(
                       Table.AddIndexColumn(AllDates, "Index", 0, 1), {"Date", "From"}
                 ),
    AllIntervals = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors( Table.AddColumn(RenameFrom, "To", each RenameFrom[From]{[Index] + 1})),


    // Join Data with all possible intervals
    InsertedCustom = Table.AddColumn(Data, "temp", each AllIntervals),
    ExpandedTable = Table.ExpandTableColumn(InsertedCustom, "temp", { "From", "To" }, { "From2", "To2" }),
    ExpandedTableWithValidValue = Table.AddColumn(ExpandedTable, "ValidValue", each ( if ([From] < [To2] and [To] > [From2]) then [Value] else 0) ), 
    ExpandedTableRevised = Table.RenameColumns( Table.RemoveColumns (ExpandedTableWithValidValue , { "Value", "From", "To" } ) , {  { "ValidValue", "Value" }, {"From2", "From"}, { "To2", "To" } } ),

    // Group and sum Data
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(ExpandedTableRevised, List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(ExpandedTableRevised), { "Value" } ), {{"Value", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Role]), "Role", "Value", List.Sum),
    #"Summed By Role" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Sum", each List.Sum(Record.ToList(Record.RemoveFields(_, { "From", "To" }))) ),

    // Transpose data with intervals, values and sum to target result structure
    ResultDataTable = Table.Transpose(#"Summed By Role"),

    // Create First column with labels for result structure
    FirstColumnRoles= Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(SourceTable, "Role")),
    FirstColumnWithFromToLabels =  Table.InsertRows(FirstColumnRoles, 0, { [Role="From"], [Role="To"] }),
    FirstColumnWithSum = Table.InsertRows ( FirstColumnWithFromToLabels , Table.RowCount(FirstColumnWithFromToLabels ), {[Role="Sum"]}),
    FirstColumn = Table.AddIndexColumn(FirstColumnWithSum , "Index", 0, 1),

    // Merge First column of labels with data structure and clean up redundant columns
    ResultTable = Table.RemoveColumns(
                          Table.ReorderColumns( Table.Join( FirstColumn, "Index", Table.AddIndexColumn(ResultDataTable , "Index", 0, 1), "Index"), { "Index", "Role"}),
                          "Index"
                      ),

    Custom1 = ResultTable

in
    Custom1
```

Comment: The result of this query doesn't exactly match your example. For instance, you're getting extra 15.01-16.01 interval. Also I don't understand why would you need such a transposed results. See my version of your code below.

Comment: Thanks, my first experience with power query:-)  You'require right about dates. Comes down to whether you treat intervals as inclusive or exclusive of end dates. Not strictly necessary to transpose, but better matches readability with business examples.

Comment: You'll find it very powerful data transformation tool! It's really great! Good luck learning!